# PLSQL/Oracle How To "Map"/"Normalize" Number

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have a `View` which takes a number called `PRIORITYPOINT` from one of its base tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_INFO
(... --all column names here)
BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS 
SELECT 
  ... -- other selected columns
  MT.PRIORITYPOINT, -- the column in question
  ... --other selected columns
FROM MTINFO MT, UTINFO UT
WHERE MT.UTID = UT.UTID 
  AND MT.EXECREADY = 'R'
  AND MT.ISEXEC > 0
```

Now, I want to change the queried `PRIORITYPOINT` into a - for lack of/not knowing better term - "normalized"/"mapped" form.

To illustrate, my `PRIORITYPOINT` may look like this:

```
76
53
99
1
0
99
345
```

And when they are "normalized"/"mapped", they should become like this:

```
3
2
4
1
0
4
5
```

What happen with the "normalization"/"mapping" above is that the wide value range of priority points (0-345) is translated into simple priority level (0-5).

At this moment, I do the "normalization" in the code that uses the table (I am coding in C#):

```
public List<InfoTable> AssignT5MOInfoViewNormalizedPriorities(List<InfoTable> list, out string eStr) {
  eStr = "";
  try {
    ... //something else
    List<double> distinctPriorities = list.Select(x => x.PriorityPoint).Distinct().ToList(); //secondly, normalize points
    distinctPriorities.Sort(); //This Sort belongs to List
    Dictionary<double, int> distinctPrioritiesDict =
      distinctPriorities.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, distinctPriorities.Count), (k, v) => new { k, v })
      .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
      list[i].PriorityPoint = distinctPrioritiesDict[list[i].PriorityPoint];
    return list;
  } catch (Exception e){ //for whatever reason, doesn't matter for now...
    eStr = e.ToString();
    //something else
    return null;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do the "normalization"/"mapping" in `PLSQL`?

**Edit:**

I am using `Oracle` Database. I am OK with solutions using `Oracle` built-in functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the [`rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions141.htm#SQLRF00690) and [`dense_rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions052.htm#SQLRF00633) functions in Oracle SQL to get the normalized value.
E.g.

```
SELECT 
  MT.PRIORITYPOINT
  , RANK()       OVER (ORDER BY MT.PRIORITYPOINT ASC)     AS EXAMPLE1
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MT.PRIORITYPOINT ASC) - 1 AS EXAMPLE2
  ... --other selected columns
FROM MTINFO MT, UTINFO UT
WHERE MT.UTID = UT.UTID 
  AND MT.EXECREADY = 'R'
  AND MT.ISEXEC > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is *almost* there, but not yet... :( because the `Rank` you show will not handle duplicate items. In the above example, I got the result like: `0 1 2 3 4 4 6` - note that the `5` is missing. Any other suggestion? (Nevertheless, you have my upvote for the closeness)

Comment: you can use DENSE_RANK instead

Comment: @Ian `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MT.PRIORITYPOINT ASC) - 1`